# knockoutjs observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to create a facebook wall-like application.

Is there a way that I can add entities to the top of array rather than at the bottom so that I can get a wall like appearance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `observableArray.unshift` to add values to the start of the array.

> myObservableArray.unshift('Some new value') inserts a new item at the beginning of the array

You can read more about it [in the observableArray documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).

Comment: To Joachim Isaksson's point, it is worth noting that `.unshift(...)` is a [standard](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.4.4.13) method of ordinary arrays as well.